# Use hippie-expand to complete ruby symbols without prefix

Tags: completion, ruby-mode, dabbrev, hippie-expand

I am an avid `hippie-expand` user but I find it annoying that it natively doesn't complete ruby symbols without the prefix. For example (cursor is `|`):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :some_action

  protected

  def some_a|

  end
end
```

If I trigger `hippie-expand` here, it doesn't know that `:some_action` is also a completion option without the `:` prefix.

What is the cleanest way to extend `hippie-expand` (or perhaps `dabbrev-expand`) to do this?

Comment: Yeah, it annoys me as well. So far, though, the best idea I've got is to change the syntax of `:` in ruby-mode back to punctuation. It will require quite a few changes to the code, in different places.

Answer (score 2):

@Dmitry made a great point that `hippie-expand` will do what I'm desiring when `:` is considered a punctuation character.

It's obviously not ideal to just set `(modify-syntax-entry ?: "." ruby-mode-syntax-table)` in your init and call it a day, because then only `some_action` in `:some_action` is considered a symbol which would break expectations for other plugins. This seems ripe for re-defining with advice though.

Here's what I came up with:

```
(defun hippie-expand-ruby-symbols (orig-fun &rest args)
  (if (eq major-mode 'ruby-mode)
      (let ((table (make-syntax-table ruby-mode-syntax-table)))
        (modify-syntax-entry ?: "." table)
        (with-syntax-table table (apply orig-fun args)))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'hippie-expand :around #'hippie-expand-ruby-symbols)
```

If `hippie-expand` is called when the major-mode is `ruby-mode`, define a cloned temporary syntax table where `:` is a punctuation character and call `hippie-expand` with it. Otherwise, just call `hippie-expand` as normal.

Any downside to this approach?

Comment: This is a pretty great approach, actually. Here's a possible tweak: instead of `major-mode` comparison, you should be able to call `advice-add` in `ruby-mode-hook`, if you replace `'hippy-expand` with `(local 'hippy-expand)`.